# How can I create a more custom function in FlutterFlow?

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I'm trying to create a custom function in FlutterFlow, but I need it to take in a `ScrollController` as a parameter and return a `Widget`.

FlutterFlow won't let me set these options in custom functions, it won't let me save anything with a `ScrollController` parameter as a custom action, and it won't let me edit the main.dart file to put the function there.

Is it possible to create this function in FlutterFlow?

Some context:

I have a custom scrollbar that I'm using throughout my app. I want to use this function to attach it to an widget's scroll controller. My current available option is to copy the scrollbar widget code and put it in every custom scrollable widget I create.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only pass supported types as parameters. Perhaps you can try passing an action to your custom code instead, like a callback.